# Why position is changing when I rotate the view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple website with some divs. When I rotate the view from horizontal to vertical it should behave like this:

https://www.loom.com/share/c7cab98155aa4f05a9a8f6319625fbc6

But it behaves like this:

https://www.loom.com/share/b43c6c51792f49a29a3d9582d9fffc4c

The only difference is in the second example the div #nav is fixed position.

It seems like this strange behavior on rotation is happening when:

- the divs have height in the vh units
- the nav div is fixed or sticky

Is there a way to make it stay in the same position on rotation when the nav div is sticky and other divs have height in the vh units?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    display: block;
    margin:0px;
    height: 30px;
}

div {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#first {
    background-color: green;
}
#second {
    background-color: blue;
}
#third {
    background-color: red;
}
#fourth {
    background-color: cyan;
}
#fifth {
    background-color: pink;
}
#sixth {
    background-color: orange;
}

#nav {
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
     <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="nav">

    </div>
    <div id="first">
        <p>Some text in the first div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <p>Some text in the second div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        <p>Some text in the third div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fourth">
        <p>Some text in the fourth div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fifth">
        <p>Some text in the fifth div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sixth">
        <p>Some text in the sixth div</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens to the navbar after rotation is applied when you inspect the element. Does  it go to ```top: 0%; ```?

Comment: As you can see in the second video the navbar is on the top - that is good. The problem is with the color divs - they jump on rotation to very different positions.

Comment: Oh, so you don't want the nav bar to be sticky both on horizontal and vertical view?

Comment: I want the navbar to be sticky both on horizontal and vertical views. But what is most important to me is not the navbar behavior but the behavior of color divs in the background. When you look carefully - they jump to different positions when rotating.

Comment: that's because you didn't assign them a specific position for every div. Give them a position top values for each div and they wont swap positions

Answer (score 0):

use   `position: absolute;`  in the place of   `position: fixed;` for top navbar.

Comment: You are right when I use position: absolute the behavior is exactly the same as in the first video. But it is not exactly what I need. Maybe I was not precise in the question. But I need the top navbar to be visible all the time in the top - like in the second video but I need the other divs (color) to behave like in the first video - when rotating they keep position - they do not jump to different positions.

Comment: you can do this using javascript as shown by the @paszo in the answer but don't forget to add  z-index = 10 ; in top navbar . I hope that's what you want.

Comment: Kindly infrom me if you want to do this with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I am not sure if it is the best possible solution but at this moment it is ok for me.

here is the link to the correct behavior:

https://www.loom.com/share/42edf3921c4349eab586fc176892c381

Here is the code that solved the problem:

```js
let divnav = document.querySelector('#nav');


window.addEventListener("orientationchange", () =>{
    console.log('on orientation change - nav disappearing ...')
    divnav.style.display = 'none';
})

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    console.log('on resize - nav appearing again ;) ');
    divnav.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    display: block;
    margin:0px;
    height: 30px;
}

div {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#first {
    background-color: green;
}
#second {
    background-color: blue;
}
#third {
    background-color: red;
}
#fourth {
    background-color: cyan;
}
#fifth {
    background-color: pink;
}
#sixth {
    background-color: orange;
}

#nav {
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="nav">

    </div>
    <div id="first">
        <p>Some text in the first div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <p>Some text in the second div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        <p>Some text in the third div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fourth">
        <p>Some text in the fourth div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fifth">
        <p>Some text in the fifth div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sixth">
        <p>Some text in the sixth div</p>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="myscirpt.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index: 10;`  in #nav in your solution.